# Arbitrarily large number of sockets - Python

Tags: python, sockets, server-side

I recently started searching for socket programming, and decided to use python for testing. I have the following question: As I read, you can only listen for a limited number of connections in a server-side socket, thus you can only have such a number of connections operating at a time. Is there a way to be able to hold as many sockets open as the system can tolerate? That is e.g. in the case of a chat server (you would not want to only have 5 active users at a time, for example).

What's the solution to that? Should one create more sockets to achieve that goal? But then, would the number of ports available to the system be the next limitation?

Comment: Do you mean small argument you give to 'listen' function?

Comment: Yes, and documentation specifies that there is a system-dependent maximum value - probably rather small.

Comment: Shall I delete it? Although I think my misunderstanding is quite clear in this question about the actual role of `listen`, while on the other question the one who asks does understand its role, but wishes to overcome the limitation. Since I got what I wanted to be clarified, if you really think this question is unnecessary, I will delete it.

Comment: I think you should delete the question. It seems to me that both the authors seem concerned about the parameter to `listen` when in fact repeatedly calling `accept` should be occurring faster than the listen queue can grow. The number of simultaneous connections is a different parameter to the argument to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about function 'listen':

> 'backlog' argument is the maximum length to which the  queue  of **pending**  connections  for  socket  may  grow.
>
> If a connection request arrives when  the  queue  is full,  the client may receive an error with an indication of ECONNREFUSED or, if the underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds.

This does not set any limit on number of socket connections. Only the ones which were not 'accept'-ed yet (e.g. have not become 'connection').

When client tries to connect the backlog grows by 1.

When you call 'accept' the backlog decreases by 1.

So if you will call 'accept' periodically you will open a number of connections.

Comment: So if another socket tries to connect while the queue is full, is its connection cancelled?

Comment: It may or may not, depending on implementations. See update.

Comment: Usually you don't need to worry about the backlog. Just make sure you accept() a connection as soon as it becomes ready. E.g. if you do event-based (single thread) programming, you would make a blocking select() call with the file descriptors of all established connections plus the server socket.